# ClojureScript. Reset atom in Reagent when re-render occurs

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm displaying a set of questions for a quiz test and I'm assigning a number to each question just to number them when they are shown in the browser:

```
(defn questions-list
 []
  (let [counter (atom 0)]
    (fn []
      (into [:section]
           (for [question @(re-frame/subscribe [:questions])]
              [display-question (assoc question :counter (swap! counter inc))])))))
```

The problem is that when someone edits a question in the browser (and the dispatch is called and the "app-db" map is updated) the component is re-rendered but the atom "counter" logically starts from the last number not from zero. So I need to reset the atom but I don't know where. I tried with a *let* inside the anonymous function but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'd just remove the state entirely. I haven't tested this code, but your thinking imperatively here. The functional version of what your trying to do is something along the lines of:
Poor but stateless:

```
(let [numbers (range 0 (count questions))
      indexed (map #(assoc (nth questions %) :index %) questions)]
  [:section
   (for [question indexed]
     [display-question question])])
```

but this is ugly, and nth is inefficient. So lets try one better. Turns out map can take more than one collection as it's argument.

```
(let [numbers (range 0 (count questions))
      indexed (map (fn [idx question] (assoc question :index idx)) questions)]
  [:section
   (for [question indexed]
     [display-question question])])
```

But even better, turns out there is a built in function for exactly this. What I'd actually write:

```
[:section
 (doall
  (map-indexed
   (fn [idx question]
     [display-question (assoc question :index idx)])
   questions))]
```

Note: None of this code has actually been run, so you might have to tweak it a bit before it works. I'd recommend looking up all of the functions in [ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/) to make sure you understand what they do.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `counter` to be just an index for a question, you could instead use something like this:

```
(defn questions-list
 []
  (let [questions @(re-frame/subscribe [:questions])
        n (count questions)]
    (fn []
      [:section
        [:ul
          (map-indexed (fn [idx question] ^{:key idx} [:li question]) questions)]])))
```

Note: here I used `[:li question]` because I assumed that `question` is some kind of text.

Also, you could avoid computing the `count` for questions in this component and do it with a [layer 3 subscription](https://github.com/day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/subscriptions.md):

```
(ns your-app.subs
  (:require
   [re-frame.core :as rf]))

;; other subscriptions...

(rf/reg-sub
 :questions-count
 (fn [_ _]
   [(rf/subscribe [:questions])])
 (fn [[questions] _]
   (count questions)))
```

Then in the `let` binding of your component you would need to replace `n (count questions)` with `n @(re-frame/subscribe [:questions-count])`.